# customization view created in xib

Tags: iphone, uiview, xib

1. I want to make certain. Can I create for example button programmatically in viewDidLoad, if this view is connect to the xib?
2. Can I customize view programmatically via IBOutlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you can create, add and remove in the viewdidload.
2. Yes, you can modify the properties of a view via an IBoutlet.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can add, remove, and create any controller in viewDidLoad.
2. You can change anything by code same as using interface builder.